# Python Quora Script

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver

I have gotten this code off of a forum and I have installed all the dependencies but I get a few errors.

I dont know python very well so I decided to look it up, I was not able to fix it that way.

```
#all cats are yellow
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
#Quora Login Information
email=""
passy=""
# File With Questions Here
filey = "fileys.txt"
#Read File ,strip new lines ,return question list
def readFile(filey):
with open(filey, "r") as f:
    q = f.readlines()
qlist = [x.strip() for x in q]
# qlist=reversed(qlist) #Will reverse the question list if needed
print len(qlist), "Total Questions Loaded"
return qlist
#Login to Quora
def login(email, passy):
print "Logging in..."
driver.get("http://quora.com")
# Create Soup Object and find all form_column classes
forms = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml").find_all(class_="form_column")
# Iterate through forms
# Find polymorphic id string,append a hashtag(#) to create css_selector
for form in forms:
    try:
        # This is for email/password entry box
        data = form.find("input")["name"]
        if data == "email":
            email_css = "#" + form.find("input")["id"]
        if data == "password":
            password_css = "#" + form.find("input")["id"]
    except:
        pass
    try:
        # This is for the Login Button
        data = form.find("input")["value"]
        if data == "Login":
            button_css = "#" + form.find("input")["id"]
    except:
        pass
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(email_css).send_keys(email)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(password_css).send_keys(passy)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(button_css).click()
time.sleep(2)
# LOGIN FINISHED
#Create Question List
qlist = readFile(filey)
#Create Webdriver Vroom Vroom
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#Total Questions Posted Counter
county=0
# Iterate through qlist ask questions till no more
for question in qlist:
try:
    print question
    driver.get("http://quora.com")
    soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")

    # Find all text areas
    blox = soup.find_all("textarea")

    # Find polymorphic id string for Ask Question entry field
    for x in blox:
        try:
            placeholder = x["placeholder"]
            if placeholder.__contains__("Ask or Search Quora"): # Fix this later
                askbar_css = "#" + x["id"]
                print askbar_css
        except:
            pass
    askbutton = "#" + soup.find(class_="AskQuestionButton")["id"]# Fix this later

    # Type out Question
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(askbar_css).send_keys(question)

    # Wait for askbutton to become clickable
    time.sleep(.2) # Fix later
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(askbutton).click()
    except:
        #Click Failed # Fix later
        pass

    # Find the popup
    while True:
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
            popExists = soup.find(class_="Modal AskQuestionModal")
            break
        except:
            pass
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
    popup = "#" + soup.find(class_="submit_button modal_action")["id"]
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(popup).click()

    for x in range(0,17):
        time.sleep(.1)
        try:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
            popExists = soup.find(class_="PMsgContainer") #Found Popup

            if str(popExists).__contains__("You asked"): #big no no
                county += 1
                break
        except:
            pass
    print "county=>",county
except Exception,e:
    print e
    print "ERROR"
    pass
```

So the code opens chrome and it loads quora, however it gets stuck on logging in and the script ends. I am also on a mac. I get the following error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
ERROR
```

Comment: What are your errors? What lines are they on?

Comment: The errors are listed, I didnt get any line numbers.